# dpkg-buildpackage get error with apt-get source nginx

Tags: nginx, apt-get, dpkg

I wanna install ngx_pagespeed on ubuntu 12.04 precise version. get nginx 1.4.4 from source

`apt-get source nginx`

chech dependence for nginx.
add page_speed module then

`dpkg-buildpackage -b`

get error, i through would be ngx_pagespeed wrong, then remove added line and dpkg again.

strange, still get same error like below:

```
        --with-mail_ssl_module \
        --add-module=/root/pagespeed/nginx-1.4.4/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam \
        --add-module=/root/pagespeed/nginx-1.4.4/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module \
        --add-module=/root/pagespeed/nginx-1.4.4/debian/modules/nginx-echo \
        --add-module=/root/pagespeed/nginx-1.4.4/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair \
        --add-module=/root/pagespeed/nginx-1.4.4/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module \
         >config.status.full
make: *** [config.status.full] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

why i use clean source package to build it still get wrong？

please help, been confused long time. thanks